# Lazy load images in slick_slider are not being used by CDN

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, cdn, slick.js

I am having an issue with my slider. We use [Slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) which we like very much.. However we noticed via dev tools that only the first image in our slider is being used by our CDN. While the others which are using lazy load functionality is not being used by the CDN

[This is how the cdn works](https://wpengine.com/support/how-does-a-cdn-work/)

We use wpengine.com to host our wordpress site. They have max-cdn built into our install and all images we use on the site or upload to the media library are "CDN" links when you look at them in dev tools.

So in our Header.php we have slider html like this:

```
<section class="lazy fade single-item slider" style="max-height:324px; 
overflow:hidden;">
    <a class="slide-link" href="#">
        <div>
            <img src="/images/img1.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="slide-link laz-slide" href="#">
        <div>
            <img data-lazy="/images/img2.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="slide-link laz-slide" href="#">
        <div>
            <img data-lazy="/images/img3.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</section>
```

You will notice that the first image tag is using **src=""** while the other images are using **data-lazy=""**

This lazy load function is built into [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) - if you hit *ctrl+f* on that link and search "lazy" you can see how they reference it on the github page

My problem is that the image that are relyig on **data-lazy=""** for lazy loading are not being used by our **CDN**. However if i simply change them to **src=""** and save, when i check in dev tools it shows them all being loaded by **CDN**.

Can anyone think of a relatively simply solution that allows me to use both lazy-load and the CDN for my [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) images?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hai Its working for me... please check the code and check this example [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/abianjali00/pen/eERXov)

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
      $(".regular").slick({
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      });
      
    });
```

```css
.slider {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
        color: black !important;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>

<section class="regular slider">
<div>
  <img data-lazy="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg">
</div>
<div>
  <img data-lazy="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-under-mist-morning-amazing-260nw-1725825019.jpg">
</div>
<div>
  <img data-lazy="https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/3MbF54EhWUhsXunc5Keueb/60774fbbff86e6bf6776f1e17a8016b4/04-nature_721703848.jpg?fit=fill&w=480&h=270">
</div>
<div>
  <img data-lazy="https://www.readree.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Search-Engines-That-Search-for-Duplicate-images.jpg">
</div>
<div>
  <img data-lazy="https://www.readree.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Search-Engines-That-Search-for-Duplicate-images.jpg">
</div>
<div>
  <img data-lazy="https://vinusimages.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/EG7A2390.jpgA_.jpg">
</div>
  <div>
  <img data-lazy="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/environment-earth-day-hands-trees-growing-seedlings-bokeh-green-background-female-hand-holding-tree-nature-field-gra-130247647.jpg">
</div>
  <div>
  <img data-lazy="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-54559212,width-748,height-499,resizemode=4,imgsize-307081/.jpg">
</div>
  <div>
  <img data-lazy="https://st.depositphotos.com/1428083/2946/i/600/depositphotos_29460297-stock-photo-bird-cage.jpg">
</div>
  <div>
  <img data-lazy="https://www.whatsappimages.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Boys-Feeling-Very-Sad-Images-Pics-Downlaod.jpg">
</div>
  </section>
```

Comment: this is not working at all. No image loaded

Comment: @someoneuseless Hi, I updated the code. Its because of image source issue.. i updated in the codepen also... please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "data-lazy" in IMG SRC, It's working fine with lazy load images.

Answer (score 0):

that seems you are using jquery slim cdn.
use

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js
```

instead of that